# Extracting data based on data in multiple columns and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have the following data which represents a call flow coming into our centre and being transferred to a consultant (CSO).

```
CallID   Sequence    Action          Location         Input    NextLocation

1135     0           CallStart       NULL             NULL     NULL    
1135     1           MenuStart       EFTPosHelpDesk   NULL     NULL    
1135     2           KeyPress        EFTPosHelpDesk   3        TransferCSO
1135     3           TransferEntry   EFTPosHelpDesk   NULL     NULL
1135     4           TransferFlag    NULL             NULL     NULL
1135     5           AccessNum       NULL             NULL     NULL
1135     6           Transfer        NULL             NULL     NULL
1135     7           Hangup          NULL             NULL     NULL
```

I'm using MS SQL Management Studio 2005 to extract the data, however the data itself is stored on a MS SQL 2000 server.

There are literally millions of calls recorded in the database and I need to extract the CallID's where a customer was transferred to a CSO. The target data that tells me a call was transferred to a CSO is exactly as follows:

```
@Sequence 2 -> NextLocation = 'TansferCSO'
@Sequence 3 -> Action = 'TransferEntry'
@Sequence 4 -> Action = 'TransferFlag'
@Sequence 5 -> Action = 'AccessNum'
@Sequence 6 -> Action = 'Transfer'
@Sequence 7 -> Action = 'Hangup'
```

... and it's always in that sequence, but the "Sequence" numbering and "Location" will vary as some calls can run for 50 - 70 steps on average and we have 100's of IVRs (Locations).

I'm fairly new to SQL and I've tried using FETCH and IF / ELSE but without success. ROW_NUMBER() wont work due to the data being on a MS SQL2000 server.

Any examples or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the pattern of actions always occur on consecutive sequence numbers, even if the initial sequence number is unpredictable?

Comment: Hi guys. Yes they occur consecutively, however the numbering can be different, for example the TransferCSO under NextLocation could occur on sequence 33, so sequences 34 to 38 would be where I need to look for the right "Action"s.

Comment: I feel five `JOIN`s of the table with itself coming on.  The condition for each is the prior sequence + 1 and the next expected action.  With an index on `CallId`/`Sequence` and including `Action` it might provide same day performance.  The real trick is accomodating enough slop to handle the flukey logger.

Comment: @HABO - I tried something similar but it took over 8 hours to get the data back and that was just for the month of April. The data I've shown in my question is already the product of several ref tables being joined. RichardTheKiwi's solution seems to have worked well with the test data I've got except it does skip duplicate entries, I'll run two queries in that case, one to filter out duplicates and another with the Richard's solution ... fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you all the calls (CallID's) that have been transferred to CSO based on all 6 of the entries being present (in any sequence).

```
  select CallID
    from yourTable
   where Action in ('TransferEntry', 'TransferFlag',
                    'AccessNum', 'Transfer', 'Hangup')
      or NextLocation = 'TransferCSO'
group by CallID
  having count(distinct Action) = 6;
```

**Note: The assumption is that the row with `NextLocation='TransferCSO'` has a different *but specific* action, e.g. "KeyPress"**

---

If you absolutely need to ensure that the 6 events are consecutive, you can use the below. A minor variation to the JOIN conditions at the end can also be used for in-order without being necessarily consecutive.

```
create table #tmpCalls (CallID int, Sequence int, Action varchar(20));

select c.CallID, c.Sequence, c.Action
  from
(
      select CallID
        from yourTable
       where Action in ('TransferEntry', 'TransferFlag',
                        'AccessNum', 'Transfer', 'Hangup')
          or (Action = 'KeyPress' and NextLocation = 'TransferCSO')
    group by CallID
      having count(distinct Action) = 6
) a
  join yourTable c on c.CallID = a.CallID
 where c.Action in ('TransferEntry', 'TransferFlag',
                    'AccessNum', 'Transfer', 'Hangup')
    or (c.Action = 'KeyPress' and c.NextLocation = 'TransferCSO');

create clustered index #ix_tmpCalls on #tmpCalls(CallID, Sequence, Action);

select distinct a.CallID
  from #tmpCalls a                 -- or perhaps just:  b.Sequence > a.Sequence
  join #tmpCalls b on b.Action = 'TransferEntry' and b.Sequence = a.Sequence + 1
  join #tmpCalls c on c.Action = 'TransferFlag' and c.Sequence = b.Sequence + 1
  join #tmpCalls d on d.Action = 'AccessNum' and d.Sequence = c.Sequence + 1
  join #tmpCalls e on e.Action = 'Transfer' and e.Sequence = d.Sequence + 1
  join #tmpCalls f on f.Action = 'Hangup' and f.Sequence = e.Sequence + 1
 where a.Action = 'KeyPress' and a.NextLocation = 'TransferCSO';
```

Note that the subquery is the original query to narrow down the candidates. The temporary table is used to make it perform quickly since we can cluster it around the 3 columns.

Comment: This doesn't require the presence of all six entries, just six sequence numbers for any combination of actions, e.g. 3 Transfers and 3 AccessNums.  That might not be a possible combination, but it's up to the OP to understand.  More than six, e.g. an extra Transfer, will cause the call to be ignored.

Comment: @HABO You are right. I have corrected to count on `Action`. Thanks!

Comment: @ HABO ... Having a extra Action may be there in the data as the logger that uploads the data has a fit sometimes and doubles up on some calls. The sequence of the Transfer actions however never changes.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - Thanks for the code. I'm trying it out now.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - I extracted about 20 calls of varying types ensuring some were transfers and some weren't. It worked like a charm. Thanks!!!